# Openerp cannot connect to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

My Server is Centos 6.4 64 bit, ip 192.168.7.4 , postgresql-server-8.4.20-1.el6_5.x86_64 installed.

```
[root@backup soft]# netstat -tupln | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27533/postmaster
tcp        0      0 :::5432                     :::*                        LISTEN      27533/postmaster
```

I installed Openerp 7.0 , by running "python setup.py install" , created db "openerp" in postgresql.
When I try to access openerp by web browser : 192.168.7.4:8069, it shows error ""FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user \"openerp\""
I cannot login to openerp db in postgresql :

```
psql -d openerp -U openerp -W
Password for user openerp:
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "openerp"
```

I'm sure that password is same with /etc/openerp-server.conf

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = openerp
db_password = *********
```

This is my /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf

```
local   all         all                               ident
host    all             all     127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all         all         192.168.7.4/32          ident
```

One more question, how can I remove openerp completely ? I want to reinstall openerp.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to reset the password of openerp user to do that follow those instructions:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

after that enter the password of root user, than enter to `psql` and write this query :

```
ALTER USER openerp WITH PASSWORD '<fill with wathever password you want>';
```

and try to run openerp with the new password.

---

for the execution of openerp i'm not sure for the command that you run openerp.
for me i'm using this command :

```
python openerp-server -r <db_user> -w <password_db_user>
```